# zombie django qcluster shows up as soon as I start redis broker

Tags: python, django, redis

I am using redis request broker with django. When I run "$ python manage.py qinfo" I see a Cluster is running but Idle. I did not start this cluster. When I start a cluster I run "$ python manage.py qcluster" and I see 2 clusters with qinfo. I can kill the cluster I started with Ctrl+C but the zombie cluster remains. Power cycling dosn't help since the zombie cluster comes back to life as soon as I start redis. Any idea on how to kill the zombie cluster or remove it from redis memory so it does't come back to life?

Comment: I found a way to kill the cluster. 1. I disabled redis db save. Then run a script to print the process id's for pusher, monitor and sentinel. Then killed these processes. Here is the script: from django_q.monitor import Stat

for stat in Stat.get_all(): print(stat.pusher, stat.monitor, stat.sentinel)